# Why UISearchController disappears when typing on UISearchBar?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

```
func configureSearchController() {
    // Initialize and perform a minimum configuration to the search controller.
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

    // Add search bar to View.
    self.view.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)

    searchController.searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    view.bringSubview(toFront: searchController.searchBar)

    //add constraints on searchbar
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchController.searchBar, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchController.searchBar, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchController.searchBar, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.topLayoutGuide, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchController.searchBar, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute,multiplier: 1, constant: 64))

}
```

So that was my code, I added a searchController searchbar as subview to a View. I added constraints as well.

Whenever I type something in the search bar, the whole thing disappears, and also the navigation bar in an animated fashion.

**First it looks like this**
[image: So it looks like this]

**Then when I start typing, it's gone** 
[image: Poof It's gone]

Comment: Its a Default behaviour for UISearchController, Can u Please attach screenshot.

Comment: try playing with this settings  self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true or self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true

Comment: It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

searchController1.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your ViewController

```
    definesPresentationContext = true
```